# Class annotation 'DisallowConcurrentExecution' in Quartz.net doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, repeat, quartz.net

I've got a `Job` class with method, that get the data from the DB and save the latest data to the static field.

But it gets data very often, so the problem could be with delays, that `the previous job won't finish before the timer would run the next job`.

So I used annotation `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]`, but it seems to do completely nothing.

How can I use this `DisallowConcurrentExecution` in the other way?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this keyword in your `Module` in which you're creating this service at the startup.

`j.DisallowConcurrentExecution();`

```
 services.AddQuartz(
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

            cfg.ScheduleJob<YourJobClass>(
                t => t.WithSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.RepeatMinutelyForever(1)),
                j =>
                {
                    j.WithIdentity(typeof(YourJobClass).FullName!).WithDescription("My job");
                    j.DisallowConcurrentExecution();
                });
```